# ASP.NET Web Api client to upload file. Pass object to post method

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to upload file to DB server through Web API client

VB class as below

```
Public Class Uploads
Public Property FileName As String
Public Property uploadDateTime As DateTime
Public Property File As Byte()
End Class
```

Then ASP.NET user upload the file using ASP.NET web form. After receieving this file we need to upload it to server through httpClient

```
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then

        Dim newFile As New Uploads()

        newFile.FileName=FileUpload1.FileName
        newFile.uploadDateTime=DateTime.Now

        newFile.File = New Byte(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength) {}
        FileUpload1.FileContent.Read(newFile.File, 0, FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength)

'Following class makes a call to web api
    Dim client As New apiClient()
    client.Upload(newFile)
        End if
```

Client for Web API
   (This is where I am struck. How do we pass a class object to web api through http client).

```
 Public Function Upload(ByVal newFile As Uploads)As Boolean


        Dim client As New HttpClient()
        client.BaseAddress = New Uri("http://localhost:8080/api/Upload")
        Dim content = New MultipartFormDataContent()

        'What I should do here to make a call to web api (cross domain)

return true
End Function
```

And then request should come to web api controller which finally will save the file to database through Entity Framework

```
<HttpPost()> _
    Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal newFile As Uploads)
        Using db As New DataContext()
            db.Uploadss.Add(newFile)
            db.SaveChanges()
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Any Code snippets will be very helpfull

Comment: Are you having issues with CORS (cross domain) or the file upload part? If it is with CORS, try to get the file upload working without CORS first, then add in the CORS. This is a good example in C# of an in memory file upload: https://conficient.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/async-file-uploads-with-mvc-webapi-and-bootstrap/

Comment: This is SOA. Web Server can receive the file from browser (ASP.NET form) but it can't save directly to database. It need to go through service so I need a client which gets the file from web server and then make a call to web api service which save that file to database. Because of security concern web server is not allowed to make Ajax call directly and somehow company still using .NET 4.0 so they need client in WEB API 1. I m finding all working examples in .NET 4.5. Not sure even if this is possible or not

Comment: I've done this before with technology much older than .NET 4.0, so it is possible.  The Web app is going to have to stream the file into bytes to pass it to the service (WebAPI).  When I've done this before, we were using WCF and had to set it up to accept a "large binary".  There will definitely be some settings you'll have to change in the service's config to allow for large packages.  Keep digging and come back and post specific questions if you run into trouble.