# Is it possible to pass Complex type to post method in web api1 with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have a class as below

```
public class Upload
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid ID{ get;set;}
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    public byte[] File { get; set; }   
    public string FileContentType { get; set; }
}
```

And I needed a http or webClient to call an web api post method which accepts this complex (object) type object.

I can see many examples in Web api 2 which required .net 4.5 but I need some working example in Web API 1 which works in .NET 4.0

Sad, but this is true many companies still on .NET 4.0 and has no plan to move to 4.5 but they need all the features in their .NET application.

So could you please tell if this is possible or not?

I need a .net client either with HttpClient or WebClient or if there is any other library!

Cheers

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you have any problems to do it, please post your code and we'll go from there

Comment: Thanks Claudio. I have sample code in another post . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347569/asp-net-web-api-client-to-upload-file-pass-object-to-post-method

Comment: I am struggling with this. This call need to make from .net 4.0 and through some http or Web Client. Not sure how this will be possible I can't get any help on this.